# BSP Application: Clients IP Address

Tags: abap, sap-bsp

Is it possible to read the clients ip address in an SAP BSP Application? We'd like to save the ip for a later moment.

The connection comes via a WebDispatcher in our DMZ to the SAP WAS.

Thanks,
h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example how to do this; create a controller and implement the `DO_REQUEST` like this:

```
method do_request.
  data remote_ip type string.
  remote_ip = request->get_header_field( `~remote_addr` ).
  write( remote_ip ).
endmethod.
```

Edit: I could not test this with a web dispatcher though.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily, that should be possible, but since you're behind a Web Dispatcher, I'd say you'll only ever see the IP of the Web Dispatcher. You'll probably have to implement some kind of logging there instead of inside the BSP application.